Сравнение значений всех соседних элементов массива
Дано: двумерный массив - 4 строки, 4 столбца.
Необходимо сравнить на равенство значение каждого элемента этого массива со значением предыдущего элемента, следующего элемента, а также со значением элементов "над" и "под" сравниваемым.
Как грамотно это можно сделать?
Попытался вот так вот коряво, но этот код не сравнивает элементы "по краям" массива.
            bool gameover = true;
            int mapSize = 4;

        for (int i = 1; i < mapSize - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < mapSize - 1; j++)
            {
                if (labelsMap[i, j].Text == labelsMap[i - 1, j].Text || labelsMap[i, j].Text == labelsMap[i, j - 1].Text || labelsMap[i, j].Text == labelsMap[i, j + 1].Text || labelsMap[i, j].Text == labelsMap[i + 1, j].Text)
                {
                    gameover = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (gameover)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Игра окончена!");
        }


Такой вариант позволяет проверить весь массив, включая последний столбец и последнюю строку, исключив вероятность возникновения IndexOutOfRangeException:
private void CheckIfGameOver()
{
    bool gameover = true;
    int mapSize = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapSize; j++)
        {
            if (i < mapSize - 1 && labelsMap[i, j].Text == labelsMap[i + 1, j].Text)
            {
                gameover = false;
                break;
            }
            if (j < mapSize - 1 && labelsMap[i, j].Text == labelsMap[i, j + 1].Text)
            {
                gameover = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (gameover)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Игра окончена!");
    }
}

ув. @rotabor, благодарю за подсказки.

Тут нужно понимать, что
labelsMap[i, j].Text == labelsMap[i + 1, j].Text

это то же самое, что и
labelsMap[i, j].Text == labelsMap[i - 1, j].Text

для следующей i.
Поэтому нужно сравнивать элементы с 0 по 2 вперёд и вниз. И всё.
P. S. Разъясняю. Вперёд и вниз означает со следующим элементом по строке и по столбцу. Выглядеть это может примерно так:
int lim = mapSize - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < lim; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < lim; j++)
        if (labelsMap[i, j].Text == labelsMap[i + 1, j].Text
            || labelsMap[i, j].Text == labelsMap[i, j + 1].Text)
            { gameover = false; break; }
    if (!gameover) break;
    if (labelsMap[i, lim].Text == labelsMap[i + 1, lim].Text
        || labelsMap[lim, i].Text == labelsMap[lim, i + 1].Text)
        { gameover = false; break; }
}

Таким образом будут выполнены все сравнения, а для последней строки и последнего столбца ещё одна команда условия.
P. P. S. @MarkShcerbakov++. Ну, и выход нужно добавить, чтоб совсем хорошо было.

Идея совершенно верная, но, вероятно, для начинающих стоит объяснить, что значит сравнивать элементы с 0 по 2 вперёд и вниз

А как значения крайнего столбца сравниваются между собой?

@MarkShcerbakov++

@rotabor спасибо. Но что такое выход?

Выход - это команда break, которая прекращает выполнение цикла. если дальше его выполнять смыла нет (как я понял алгоритм из вашего кода).

Проблемма в том что крайние клетки не обрабатыватся совсем. У них тоже есть соседи просто их меньше.
Предлгаю вынести код который ищет соседий в отдельный метод, условия добавленны что бы не выйти за пределы поля:
private IEnumerable<(int x, int y)> GetNeighboursIndexes(int x, int y, int maxX, int maxY)
{
    if (x > 0)
        yield return (x - 1, y);

    if (x < maxX)
        yield return (x + 1, y);

    if (y > 0)
        yield return (x, y - 1);

    if (y < maxY)
        yield return (x, y + 1);
}

Что бы не работать в алгоритме с полями предлагаю сделать маленькую вспомогательную функцию которая достает значение из поля
private string GetMapValue(YoureMapType[,] map, int x, int y) => map[x, y].Text;

Ну и сама функция которая пробегает по каждой клетке, получает соседей клетки и если хоть одна совпадает то считаем что проиграли
public bool IsGameOver(YoureMapType[,] map)
{
    var height = map.GetLength(1);
    var width = map.GetLength(0);

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            var currentValue = GetMapValue(map, x, y);
            var neighbours = GetNeighboursIndexes(x, y, width - 1, height - 1);
            foreach (var neighbour in neighbours)
            {
                
                var neighbourValue = GetMapValue(map, neighbour.x, neighbour.y);
                if (neighbourValue == currentValue)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

